# Property proceedure Compile error: property are inconsistemt

Tags: properties, vb6, procedure

I created a property in VB6 to Get and Set ErrorMessages
but everytime I try to run it in give me an error

> Definitions of property procedure for the same property are inconsistent, or property procedure has an optional parameter, a ParamArray, or an Invalid Set final parameter.

```
Dim sErrorMessage As String
Public Property Get ErrorMessage() As String
    '<EhHeader>
    On Error GoTo PROC_ERR
    '</EhHeader>

100     ErrorMessage = sErrorMessage
102     sErrorMessage = ""
104     bMethodFailed = False

'<EhFooter>
PROC_EXIT:
    Exit Property
PROC_ERR:
    If modErr.iHandleError(Err, Erl(), "cTag.ErrorMessage") = vbRetry    Then Resume
    Resume Next
'</EhFooter>
End Property

Public Property Set ErrorMessage(ByVal value As String)
   Set sErrorMessage = value
End Property
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing from `Set` to `Let`:

```
Public Property Let ErrorMessage(ByVal value As String)
    sErrorMessage = value
End Property
```

Comment: I did, previously but when I'm setting a string variable to the property I get a compiling error saying Object required, is that because Let is expecting an object ??

Comment: I don't have VB6 on my machine anymore, but in Excel it won't let me use `Set` with a **String** Property; it only lets me use `Let`.

Comment: Make sure you **delete** the `Set`, and only have a `Let`.  You can't have both...

Comment: Thanks I forgot to take off Set inside the property

Comment: Actually you most certainly *can* have both, though that normally only applies to a property of `Variant` type.

Comment: Right.  I meant specifically for the String property.